# Unable to access iterator data member using object

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, linked-list, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the operator+, I want to add two nodes using an iterator but I am having problems with accessing the iterator from another object.

Here is my operator+:

```
 type operator+(const largeInt<type> &other) {
     iter = list.end();
     other.iter = other.list.end() //need help here

     type newNumb1, newNumb2;

     newNumb1 = *iter;
     newNumb2 = other.*iter; //need help here

     return newNumb1 + newNumb2;
 }
```

I have this `typename List<type>::Iterator iter;` as a private data member inside the largeInt class.

The iterator class is saved in another class, it is nested within a linkedlist class that is why to make an Iterator object I have to do `List<type>::Iterator` although it works I am not able to access it using another largeInt object passed as a reference.

UPDATE:

```
 type operator+(const largeInt<type> &other) {
     typename List<type>::Iterator other_iter = other.iter; 
     type newNumb1, newNumb2;

     newNumb1 = *iter;
     newNumb2 = *other_iter;

     return newNumb1 + newNumb2;
 }
```

This worked but I want to do the same thing like this but without having to make an extra iterator, any help would be great.

Comment: How about `*other.iter`?

Answer (score 0):

In this simple example, you don't need to use any local variables at all:

```
type operator+(const largeInt<type> &other) {
    return *iter + *(other.iter);
}
```